# Oracle Connection String for RAC Environment?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-administration

I have got an ORACLE RAC Environment access .The details are

Database Name: orcl
Service Name: orcl
IP Address: 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.2

```
SQL> host srvctl status database -d orcl

Instance orcl1 is running on node orclnode1

Instance orcl2 is running on node orclnode2
```

My concern is my connection, which is being established using

```
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=
    (PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.1.1) (PORT=1521)
)(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl1)))
```

But the provider wants it to be connected via the orcl service name .

I don`t have any other info related to this. Am I connecting correctly or I need hostname or IP address for orcl service name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your connection string is referencing one instance on one server/node. You should be using the common service name instead, and identifying all the servers it is available on.

The equivalent for you would be something like this (line breaks just for clarity here):

```
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=
    (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.1.1)(PORT=1521))
    (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.1.2)(PORT=1521))
)(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)))
```

As long as it is resolvable, it shouldn't matter whether you use the DNS names or the IP addresses for the `HOST` parameters.

You may also need the `LOAD_BALANCE` or `FAILOVER` parameters; see [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/rac.112/e10718/hafeats.htm#BABEFHAA).

Comment: If only everything to do with RACs were this simple... aka woe is me ;-)