# Difference between using a TNS name and a service name in a JDBC connection

Tags: oracle, tomcat, jdbc

I have a java based server (Tomcat) that connects to an Oracle database using a JDBC connection. There are multiple ways to connect to the database: SID, TNS name, Service name.

I would like to understand what is the difference between each of these connections and what would be the recommended connection (SID, TNS, or service) if connecting to a clustered database. Here is the TNS name we have for the database:

```
MY_NICE_TNS_NAME.MY_COMPANY.COM =

(DESCRIPTION =

  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = myhostname)(PORT = 1521))

  (LOAD_BALANCE = YES)

  (CONNECT_DATA =

   (SERVER = DEDICATED)

   (SERVICE_NAME = MY_NICE_SERVICE_NAME.MY_COMPANY.COM)

   (FAILOVER_MODE =

   (TYPE = SELECT)(METHOD = BASIC)(RETRIES = 180)(DELAY = 5)

   )

  )

)
```

Thanks!

Comment: as long as you have only ONE hostname specified there is practically no difference. If you were connected to RAC(OPS) or DataGuard then yes. SID is unique, not changeable and ends with number. While the SERVICE_NAME can be present on one or more nodes. And it can also move between nodes

Comment: Thanks, great to know. See my comment below. We do have a RAC.

Comment: if you use RAC then you should specify hostname for every node. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13424385/oracle-connection-string-for-rac-environment

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Oracle SID is the unique name that uniquely identifies your instance/database where as Service name is the TNS alias that you give when you remotely connect to your database and this Service name is recorded in Tnsnames.ora file on your clients and it can be the same as SID and you can also give it any other name you want.

SERVICE_NAME is the new feature from oracle 8i onwards in which database can register itself with listener. If database is registered with listener in this way then you can use SERVICE_NAME parameter in tnsnames.ora otherwise - use SID in tnsnames.ora.

Also if you have OPS (RAC) you will have different SERVICE_NAME for each instance.

SERVICE_NAMES specifies one or more names for the database service to which this instance connects. You can specify multiple services names in order to distinguish among different uses of the same database. For example:

SERVICE_NAMES = sales.acme.com, widgetsales.acme.com

You can also use service names to identify a single service that is available from two different databases through the use of replication.

In an Oracle Parallel Server environment, you must set this parameter for every instance.

The TNS is the sql*net configuration file that defines datbases address for establishing connection to them.

Comment: We actually do have a RAC and that is the reason I am asking because if we loose a database and it happens to be the one I'm pointing to, then we loose the service. So, basically, what you are saying is that I need to be pointing to the TNS in order for it to default to one that is working. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct. In your TNS you can specify your different nodes for your RAC. In that case if one of your node goes down, the service is still available.

Answer (score 17):

`SERVICE_NAME` is a **alias** to a database instance (or many instances). The main purpose of this is if you are running a cluster. Using this we can connect specific database within a cluster. And other way, using `SID` (**S**ystem **ID**entifier) we can connect to a database instance, which is a **unique** name for an Oracle database instance.

In short, SID = the unique name of your DB, SERVICE_NAME = the alias used when connecting.

There are several ways to provide database information like Directly Specified, tnsnames.ora (i.e. TNS name), LDAP Directory, Network Information Services.

A TNS (**T**ransparent **N**etwork **S**ubstrate) name is the name of the entry in `tnsnames.ora` file which is kept in `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin`
This file contains the information which is used by the system to connect to oracle database. Using this a client can fetch server associated information transparently.  It contains the  following information

```
PROTOCOL
HOST IP ADDRESS
PORTNO
SID  or SERVICE_NAME
```

E.g

```
 mydb =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.35.15.1)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = mydb))
```

JDBC drivers connect with a connection string using TNS as follows

```
System.setProperty("oracle.net.tns_admin", PATH_TO_TNSNAMES.ORA);
Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
dbUrl = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST="+IPHOST+")(PORT="+PORT+"))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME="+DBNAME+")))"

conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
```